# Assigning objects with dynamic names in Java

Tags: java, object, dynamic, nullpointerexception

I am trying to create an object of a class with dynamic naming

```
Object1
Object2
Object3
```

So, I am trying to create a dynamic name for an object of the class Adder.

```
Adder addar[];
```

and I am trying to store that object in the ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<Adder> list= new ArrayList<Adder>();
```

Inside a printer method I have used below code.

```
addar[count] = new Adder();
addar[count].addName(theName);
addar[count].addAge(theAge);
list.add(addar[count]);
```

When I try to run the program i get this exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException<br/>
  at Moving.printer(Moving.java:65)
  at OrPGan.main(OrPGan.java:7)
```

at line

```
addar[count] = new Adder();
```

What is causing this? How can I deal with this?

Your response would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: where have u intialized    Adder addar[]; ??

Comment: Please review the answer given below, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize the array of `Adder` objects *in addition* to initializing each individual `Adder` member of that array.  Try this code:

```
Adder addar[] = new Adder[10];
ArrayList<Adder> list= new ArrayList<Adder>();

int count = 0;

addar[count] = new Adder();
addar[count].addName(theName);
addar[count].addAge(theAge);
list.add(addar[count]);
```

Comment: Thank you! Your solution solved my problem